# Error: must declare the table variable @T

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have to join 3 tables as follows

```
DECLARE @columnHeaders1 NVARCHAR (MAX), @t varchar(max)

SELECT 
   @columnHeaders1  = COALESCE (@columnHeaders1  + ',[' + LocationName + ']', '[' + LocationName + ']')
FROM
     (SELECT DISTINCT LocationName 
      FROM StockMaster 
      JOIN @t ON @t.PartNo = StockMaster.PartNo
      JOIN Locations ON StockMaster.LocationId = Locations.LocationId 
      WHERE substring(StockMaster.PartNo, 1, 2) = 01 
        AND StockMaster.Quantity > 0) PC

PRINT @columnHeaders1
```

Here `@t` is a table name which is passed as an parameter but it shows the following error

> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Must declare the table variable "@t".

How to declare it?

Answer (score 1):

You're **not** declaring a table! You're declaring `@T` as a single `VARCHAR(MAX)` variable:

```
DECLARE @t varchar(max)
```

You need to change this to something like

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ColumnName1 varchar(max))
```

or whatever it is that you need

Comment: @user3234884: then you're doing something else wrong..... can you update your original question with your new code?